# Compare two dataframes and output new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, compare

I'm a beginner in Python. I have two dataframes, each with 5 columns but only the first two columns from each dataframe have matching data. Each dataframe have different number of records. I would like to compare column **A** from **df1** against column **A** from **df2** and if they match, then output column **D** (ownerEmail) from df2. If columns A don't match, column D should be null.

**df1**

```
subscriptionId | displayName | state   | authorization | tenantId
12345          | DEV_SPS     | Enabled | RoleBased     | 938c49a8
67890          | PROD_LINUX  | Enabled | RoleBased     | 0a9cb9ee
11900          | TST_WIN     | Enabled | RoleBased     | e1513511
```

**df2**

```
subscriptionId | SubName    | Connected | ownerEmail         | organization
12345          | DEV_SPS    | Enabled   | john.doe@gmail.com | Marketing
67890          | PROD_LINUX | Enabled   | alex.bre@gmail.com | Sales
```

**Desired output**

```
subscriptionId | displayName | state   | authorization | tenantId | ownerEmail       
123456         | DEV_SPS     | Enabled | RoleBased     | 938c49a8 | john.doe@gmail.com
67890          | PROD_LINUX  | Enabled | RoleBased     | 0a9cb9ee | alex.bre@gmail.com
11900          | TST_WIN     | Enabled | RoleBased     | e1513511 | null
```

I have tried something like this but it didn't work.

```
df1['ownerEmail'] = np.where(df1['subscriptionId'] == df2['subscriptionId'], ['ownerEmail'], "")
print(df1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge your dataframes on `subscriptionId` column and keep all records from `df1` (`how='left'`):

```
>>> pd.merge(df1.astype({'subscriptionId': str}),
             df2[['subscriptionId', 'ownerEmail']].astype({'subscriptionId': str}),
             on='subscriptionId', how='left')

   subscriptionId displayName    state authorization  tenantId          ownerEmail
0           12345     DEV_SPS  Enabled     RoleBased  938c49a8  john.doe@gmail.com
1           67890  PROD_LINUX  Enabled     RoleBased  0a9cb9ee  alex.bre@gmail.com
2           11900     TST_WIN  Enabled     RoleBased  e1513511                 NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but not working. 

df1.merge(df2[['subscriptionId', 'ownerEmail']], on='subscriptionId', how='left')

It throws an error "You are trying to merge on object and float64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat"

Comment: Ok, there's some progress as there's no error. But the ownerEmail column shows NaN for all records. Here's what I tried:

df3 = pd.merge(df1.astype({'subscriptionId': str}),
             df2[['subscriptionId', 'ownerEmail']].astype({'subscriptionId': str}),
             on='subscriptionId', how='left')
print(df3)

Comment: Ok so I modified my dataframe slightly and followed the code that you've posted. It works! Would like to express my gratitude for your help. Thank you very much :)